# 'User' object has no attribute 'user', Where is the problem?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, password-recovery

My goal is to reset the password via mail. But the `profile_obj` of the `ChangePassword` view returns `None` and `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`. Why? I tried different ways but did not work. The `ForgetPassword` view working well. The `ChangePassword` view doesn't work. Where is the problem? give me a relevant solution.

***views.py:***

```
def ForgetPassword(request):

    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email = request.POST.get('email')

            if not User.objects.filter(email=email).first():
                messages.warning(request, 'Not email found with this email.')
                return redirect('ForgetPassword')

            user_obj = User.objects.get(email = email)
            token = str(uuid.uuid4())

            send_forget_password_mail(user_obj.email , token) 
            
            messages.success(request, 'Please check your mail box an email is send.')
            return redirect('ForgetPassword')
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    context = { 
        
    }
return render(request, "forget_password_email.html", context)


def ChangePassword(request, token):

    context = {}    

    try:
        profile_obj = User.objects.filter(forget_password_token=token).first()

        print(profile_obj)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            new_password = request.POST.get('new_password')
            confirm_password = request.POST.get('reconfirm_password')
            user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')

            if user_id is None:
                messages.warning(request, 'No user id found.')
                return redirect(f'/ChangePassword/{token}/')

            if  new_password != confirm_password:
                messages.warning(request, 'both should  be equal.')
                return redirect(f'/ChangePassword/{token}/')

            profile_obj.password = new_password
            profile_obj.save()
            user_obj = User.objects.get(id = user_id)
            user_obj.set_password(new_password)
            user_obj.save()
            return redirect('Login')

        context = {'user_id' : profile_obj.user.id}

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    context = {

    }
    return render(request,'change_password.html', context)
```

***helpers.py:***

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings 


def send_forget_password_mail(email , token ):
    subject = 'Your forget password link'
    message = f'Hi , click on the link to reset your password http://127.0.0.1:8000/ChangePassword/{token}/'
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [email]
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)   
    return True
```

***models.py:***

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, error_messages={"unique":"The email must be unique!"})

    REQUIRES_FIELDS = ["email"]
    objects = CustomeUserManager()
    forget_password_token = models.CharField(null= True, max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk}.{self.email}"
```

***urls.py:***

```
path('ForgetPassword/', views.ForgetPassword, name="ForgetPassword"),
path('ChangePassword/<token>/', views.ChangePassword, name="ChangePassword")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your context in the `ChangePassword` function is :

```
    context = {'user_id' : profile_obj.user.id}
```

Your error here is that `profile_obj` is a `QuerySet` and you are looking for a `user` field in a `queryset` and not in a model `instance`(`model`) like `user_obj`.
Also, you can't change a password this way in a queryset:

```
   profile_obj.password = new_password
   profile_obj.save()
```

This works on model instances.
You need to rewrite your view to either `get` a `User` instance and then return it's `id` to your context or use the already created `user_obj` you are getting later in your code.

```
context = {'user_id' : user_obj.id}
```

Comment: thank you for your help,, but I already solved It...